# ubuntu 13.10 does not work how can I return to ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.10

I recently intalled ubuntu 13.04, which I liked very much, and after a while a window appears asking to upgrade to ubuntu 13.10, which I did. After re-starting computer, ubuntu did not work! I would like to return to 13.04. How can I do that. I would like to remove ubuntu 13.10 from grub.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could edit the */etc/default/grub* file after *sudo* then run  *sudo update-grub* to update the */boot/grub/grub.cfg* file to change things in GRUB2.

But, the Genie's out of the bottle, and once you upgrade, downgrading is Mission Impossible. I'm not sayin' that it could not be done, hypothetically, but it surely is a complicate process, and much more difficult than backing up the contents of $HOME and below, doing a clean reinstall of 13.04, and then reimporting your data back in and making it yours once more.